# Defining a rightrotate function with non-fixed rotation length

Tags: function, parameters, verilog

I need a **rightrotate** function in Verilog for 32-Bit inputs, since it is not defined as an operator (x >>> y).

It is easy rightrotate such input by hand:

```
wire [31:0] test = 32'd12345; 
wire [31:0] rotated_1 = {test[0:0],test[31:1]};
wire [31:0] rotated_3 = {test[2:0],test[31:3]};
```

The output of a testbench is as expected:

```
original: 00000000000000000011000000111001
rotate_1: 10000000000000000001100000011100
rotate_3: 00100000000000000000011000000111
```

We see, that a function rotate(inp,x) should work like this:

```
function rotate;
   input [31:0] inp; 
   input [4:0]  x;
   begin 
      rotate = {inp[x-1:0],inp[31:x]};
   end
endfunction
```

**Problem is: x is no constant**, so it doesn't compile. To specify a range with [a:b], both a and b have to be constants.

A solution seems to be using parameters:

```
function rotate;
   parameter integer x = 1;
   input [31:0] inp;
   begin
      rotate = {inp[x-1:0],inp[31:x]};
   end
endfunction
```

Well, it does compile, but unlike modules, which you can instantiate with a changed parameter like this

```
param_module #(3) pm_inst(...);
```

,that **does not work with functions**. In fact, from reading the [grammar](http://www.verilog.com/VerilogBNF.html#REF161) of Verilog, I cannot see a way **at all** to specify the parameter:

```
<function_call>
::= <name_of_function> ( <expression> <,<expression>>* )
```

My experiments with [defparam](http://www.verilog.com/VerilogBNF.html#REF54) only worked with modules, not functions.

Since parametrized macros do not exist in Verilog either, **how should i implement the rotate function without declaring one for each possible rotation?** - and i need lots of them :-(

(**Not** like this:)

```
function rotate1...
function rotate2...
function rotate3...
...
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can simulate a rotate by concatenating two copies of the data and shifting:

```
function [31:0] rotate (input [31:0] data, input [4:0] shift);
reg [63:0] tmp;
begin
  tmp = {data, data} >> shift;
  rotate = tmp[31:0];
end
endfunction
```

Comment: Isn't this solution rather inefficient compared to the rotation by hand, since doubles the data?

Comment: How are you using the function? If you call it with a constant for the `shift` argument, any decent synthesis tool will propagate the constant and simplify the implementation to a bit permutation. If the `shift` argument takes on a limited subset of the 32 possible values, then you might be better off muxing them directly. If `shift` can be any of the 32 values, then this will be better than a naive 32x32 mux. Results will vary depending on how good your synthesis tool is. A good tool will map an unconstrained use of this function to a circular 32-bit barrel shifter, which is what you want.

Comment: Thanks a ton, this solves my question! I'm new to Verilog/FPGA programming and didn't know if such tricks get optimized away.

Answer (score 0):

Aloha!

The simple solution is to use a MUX with fixed rotation in 0-31 steps of the input and then use x as the value to switch on.

For an efficient implementation take a look at the barrel shifter. Using five 2-1 32-bit MUXes in chain shifting the input either 16, 8, 4, 2, 1 steps (for mux 0, 1, 2, 3, 4) or not based on the control bit for each mux.